# Model the equation of trajectory

Tags: classical-mechanics

I am building a physics engine for a 2d game. Im currently trying to model the equation of trajectory for a projectile (tank shell). I have successfully applied the formula: [https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y+%3D+x*tan(60)+-+(9.82+*+x%5E2)+%2F+(2+*+150%5E2+*+cos%5E2(60))](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%20%3D%20x*tan(60)%20-%20(9.82%20*%20x%5E2)%20%2F%20(2%20*%20150%5E2%20*%20cos%5E2(60))) in my code,
where 60 is the angle of the tank pipe and 150 the initial velocity.

My issue is that the "travel speed" for the projectile on the parabola is in relation to the time passed since the shot is fired. So if firing with an angle of close to 90 and the projectile travels extremely fast. Where as firing with an angle close to say 45 it travels extremely slow (using the same inital velocity).

This is my code:

```
x += elapsed*800;
y = x*tan(angle*PI/180) - (g * pow(x, 2)) / (2 * pow(power, 2) * pow(cos(angle*PI / 180), 2));
```

where elapsed is the time passed since the last frame. I suspect i need to set x in relation to the maximum height of the trajectory s  or something but i cant figure it out really.

Comment: You shouldn't express $y$ in terms of $x$, you should express both $x$ and $y$ in terms of time $t$ (and your current implementation is wrong anyway for what you were trying to do - your x is independent of the angle, for instance).

Comment: okay so basicly just do t = elapsed*800; x+=t?  but how do i use t in the equation for y?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic answer is to increment time. Not space. This means that the variable you steadily increment each iteration is time.

Now, the equations of motion must be written a function of time, not space. More precisely, you need the position (x,y,z) as a function of time. This way, the speed of moving along the trajectory will be proportional to that it takes in real life, assuming no lag from your computer.

I cannot give you the formula that depends on time because it depends on the situation. If you are just looking for a falling object, the equations are available easily [on the web](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_fall), and refinements of that should not be difficult to find.